# How to align HTML cell values

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm trying to align two cells evenly with each other but can't seem to get the right format. I have days of the week in an array, and I'd like to align them with each time of the day, which are also in a PHP array.

```
<table style='border: 1px solid red'>
    <tr>
        <td style='border: 1px solid red'>
        <?php
        $weekdays = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", 
        "friday", "saturday", "sunday");
        foreach ($weekdays as $weekday) {
        echo ucfirst($weekday) . "<br />";
            }                   
        ?>
        </td>

        <td style='border: 1px solid red'>
       <?php
       $i = 0;
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data_set)) {            
           echo "<span>" . substr($row['start_hour'], 3) . " - " . 
           substr($row['end_hour'], 3) . "</span><br />";                       
           $i++;
        }                   
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each day 'must' be in THE SAME row as it's result!

You want 7 rows () (based on days of week), make them.
Row should have 2 cells and they are inside . Which is 14  total, 2  per row.
Which is

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
        X 1 - 1
    </td>
    <td>
        X 1 - 2
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Y 2 - 1
    </td>
    <td>
        Y 2 - 2
    </td>
</tr>
```

(/how table works)
That was 2x2.

You need 7x2, 7 days (rows), 2 columns.

I do not know PHP, but I guess it should be something like adding:

for each day (!) add this to table!
    
        
            some_cool_regex_maybe_$THE_DAY
        
        
            some_cool_regex_maybe_$HOURS.MIN + " - " + some_cool_regex_maybe_$HOURS.MAX
    
    
(this should be done for every day O:-) )

Answer (score 1):

I offer to you, for handling your database result, put all datas in new array like below code:

```
$date_array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data_set)) {

    $date_array[ $row[ 'weekday' ] ] = substr($row['start_hour'], 3) . " - " . substr($row['end_hour'], 3);

}

foreach( $weekdays as $item ) {

    if ( $date_array[ $item ] )
        echo "<span>" . $date_array[ $item ] . "</span><br/>";
    else
        echo "<br/>";

}
```

Now you can use above `foreach` in your **`<TD>`** table. ( IF statement help you to control empty line )

Answer (score 1):

As said above your table structure should look like this:

```html
<table style='border: 1px solid red'>
    <tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Monday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Tuesday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Wednesday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Thursday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Friday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Saturday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>Sunday</td>
      <td style='border: 1px solid red'>09:00-17:00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However from what i understand you trying to do this might help you.

`<table style='border: 1px solid red'>
    <?php
        $weekdays = array("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday");
        $hours = array("09:00-17:00", "09:00-18:00", "09:00-16:00", "09:00-14:00", "09:00-20:00", "09:00-20:00", "09:00-21:00");
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($weekdays as $weekday) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='border: 1px solid red'>";
                    echo ucfirst($weekday);
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td style='border: 1px solid red'>";
                    echo $hours[$count];
                    $count++;
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    ?>
</table>`